# Block Postgres port 5432 running on Docker container with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, unix, postgresql, docker

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 desktop (Xubuntu to be exact), and trying to block outside access to a locally running Postgres port 5432 with iptables.  This is my `iptables -S`

```
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j DROP
```

And `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql
```

But somehow a network scanner app on my Android, connected to the same wifi, can still see it. I can further test it with a PSQL utility on my Android, and indeed I can see all my tables.  What am I missing?

Edit: might be worth mentioning that this is Postgres running on a docker container. This may have something to do with it.

Comment: I have done the same with other ports for other apps, but it has blocked them successfully. This one is persistent somehow.

Comment: What happens if you drop the accept on `lo`?  Does postgresql have any other ports open?

Comment: @chicks No. The port wasn't actually opened on the host but forwarded into the container by docker. That's why a DROP has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did more digging. This looks like Docker behavior that modifies the iptables FORWARD chain.

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-OVERLAY  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:postgresql
```

[This website](https://fralef.me/docker-and-iptables.html) outlines the issue.

To prevent Docker from forwarding all access to your container, specify `127.0.0.1` when running the container.

`docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 postgres`